# certbot using weak diffie hellman encryption

Tags: ssl, lets-encrypt, diffie-hellman, starttls, certbot

I was reading here

https://weakdh.org/

If I verify security on

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html

of one of my sites using [certbot](http://certbot.eff.org) I get rated B because of that

[image]

is there a solution?

certbot basically is the implementation of https://letsencrypt.org/ for many systems.

Comment: Probably better asked on [Information Security](https://security.stackexchange.com/) or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: LetsEncrypt is a Certificate Authority (CA) and certbot is a tool for obtaining and installing a certificate from LE. Your problems (weak DH and missing PFS) have absolutely nothing to do with your certificate and thus do not involve LE or certbot at all. They do involve your server software and its configuration, about which you provided no information, so if you ask where this is on-topic do provide information about those.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 sorry for my ignorance. I use nginx... the configuration of nginx is done by certbot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem.  The core issue is described here:
https://weakdh.org/

As I understand it, most web servers start Diffie-Hellman with the same default set of prime numbers, and this was later found to be a security flaw.  The fix is to generate new primes for your site's Diffie-Hellman key negotiation.  This page has details: https://weakdh.org/sysadmin.html

In short, run `openssl dhparam -out dhparams.pem 2048`, and then add the path to the resulting file in your nginx server config block:

```
ssl_dhparam {path to dhparams.pem};
```

For example, I put mine in `/etc/letsencrypt`, so I ran

```
sudo openssl dhparam -out /etc/letsencrypt/dhparams.pem 2048
```

and added

```
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/dhparams.pem;
```

under the other Certbot config lines in my server block.

After restarting nginx with `sudo service nginx restart` I got an A grade on ssllabs.com.

I hope this helps.

Comment: haven't verified, but will accept none the less. Will look into it when I have time

Comment: Thanks.  After I posted my answer I found this site as well:
https://www.linode.com/docs/web-servers/nginx/nginx-ssl-and-tls-deployment-best-practices/#create-a-custom-diffie-hellman-key-exchange